# Install4j ant task throwing error for license

Tags: install4j

Getting below error when running install4j ant task even if license is present in install4j(checked with install4j IDE). Tried providing license using command line 

 `install4jc -license=XXXX` 
but still getting the same error.

```
build   04-Mar-2014 03:45:51    [install4j] Executing 'C:\Program Files\install4j5\bin\install4jc.exe' with arguments:<br/>
build   04-Mar-2014 03:45:51    [install4j] '--win-keystore-password=XXXX'<br/>
build   04-Mar-2014 03:45:51    [install4j] 'C:\Users\Z_Admin\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\ZEETRUNK-BUILDALL-JOB1\trunk\installer\zbot\installer\zbot.install4j'<br/>
build   04-Mar-2014 03:45:51    [install4j] <br/>
build   04-Mar-2014 03:45:51    [install4j] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are<br/>
build   04-Mar-2014 03:45:51    [install4j] not part of the command.<br/>
build   04-Mar-2014 03:45:52    [install4j] install4j version 5.1.6 (build 5596), built on 2013-06-07<br/>
build   04-Mar-2014 03:45:52    [install4j] Please run the command line executable with the -L [license key] option or open the install4j IDE to enter a license key.<br/>
build   04-Mar-2014 03:45:52          [ant] Exiting C:\Users\Z_Admin\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\ZEETRUNK-BUILDALL-JOB1\trunk\installer\zephyr\installer\exebuild.xml.<br/>
```

Thanks,
    
Prateek

Comment: Hi. I have a related problem to disable the signing process at command line. Then I found out that the short written option term works while the other do not. For your example you may try to use the command `install4jc -L xxxxx` instead of `install4jc --license xxxxx`. Maybe that could work also for your option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you're running ant as a different user.

Copy

```
%USERPROFILE%\.install4j5\config.xml
```

to

```
[install4j installation directory]\config\config.xml
```

then the license will be available for all users,